# Spring MVC - XML response with @ResponseBody annotation (Spring + XML)

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I need to send xml reponse from my application to incoming HTTP request.
For this i reffered [THIS LINK](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/). This example returns the xml

```
<coffee>
   <name>arabica</name>
   <quantity>10<quantity>
</coffee>
```

But i need response like

```
<coffee>arabica</coffee>
```

Here there is no specific root element.
please suggest how to i get this response by modifying java object.

Early response will be really helpful

i Modified the code as below but i am not getting output expected

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "coffee")
public class Coffee
{
  String coffee;

  public String getCoffee()
  {
   return coffee;
  }

  @XmlElement
  public void setCoffee(String coffee)
  {
    this.coffee = coffee;
  }
}
```

For this code i am getting output like below

```
<coffee><coffee>arabica</coffee></coffee>
```

Comment: please provide code you did so far

Comment: @TomSebastian i have updated the code please check

Comment: XML doc without root/docElement is not a well formed xml. whatever you modified is the acceptable, still you dont want to see root element you may have to use string operations to strip out the extra <coffee></coffee>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. A xml-node can either contain (1)a value or (2)other xml-nodes, a jackson class must contain other xml-nodes.

But you can return a string instead of a instance of `Coffee`.

Try to return a String directly.

```
return "<coffee>"+coffee+"</coffee>";
```